# Rails ActiveRecord equivalent SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'%Y-%m')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking for an efficient way to do a `SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'%Y-%m')` without writing a database-specific query.

I'm using Rails 4.0.2, with the ActiveRecord pluck method, is it possible to use this with a database function, or even better achieve this without a database-specific function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do this on the rails side and not on the database?  If you do it on the rails side then you need to return all the records then filter them.

Comment: I was originally using the SQL statement above, but then decided to move the database from MySQL to Postgresql, so I need to change the code and use to_char. My question is really to see if there is a database-independent way of doing it, without returning all the records and filtering them.

Comment: Something similar to `Model.select("distinct date_format(date_col, '%Y-%m')")`?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:date_col).map {|date| date.strftime('%Y-%m') }
```

EDIT: As noted by vee, this is not a solution as it might return duplicate records.

Comment: This `uniq` is not going to be same as `distinct date_format(date_col, '%Y-%m')` is it?

Comment: @vee - Uniq itself deos not. This will first execute `SELECT DISTINCT datecol` and then will format results as requested. I doubt there is build-in, db-agnostic method in ActiveRecord to handle date_format.

Comment: @BroiSatse, correct on the formatting but you're not going to get accurate results here, distinct by `%Y-%m` is not same as uniq by date, because `date_col` at least definitely contains the day part as well.

Comment: @vee - Ah, true to that!

Comment: @BroiSatse vee Thank you both for your advice, it sounds as though I either need a database-specific SQL statement or, to be database agnostic, get all the dates back and filter them.